# Gradle maven publish doesn't work for first version

Tags: java, maven, groovy, gradle

with a build.gradle file containing:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            snapshotRepository (url: mavenSnapshotRepoUrl)
            repository (url: mavenRepoUrl) {
               authentication (userName: mavenRepoUsername, password: mavenRepoPassword)
            }
            pom {
                //groupId = project.group
                artifactId = 'myapp'
                //version = project.version
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I run the command `uploadArchives`, I get the following error:

```
$ gradlew uploadArchives
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:uploadArchives FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Error deploying artifact 'mycompany:myapp:jar': Error retrieving 
    previous build number for artifact 'mycompany:myapp:jar': repository 
    metadata for: 'snapshot mycompany:myapp:0.0.
    1-SNAPSHOT' could not be retrieved from repository: remote due to an 
    error: Authorization failed: Access denied to: http://myserver\
    /repository/snapshots/mycompany/myapp/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I've triple checked my userName and password. Is there something I'm missing or is this usual for an initial publish?

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar error message coming up today when I executed

```
$ gradle uploadArchives
```

on my Mac Book. My Mac was sitting behind Proxy server of the job. I had a remote public Artifactory repository server into which I tried upload my jar.

For the last few months, I have had dozens of problems due to Proxy intervension. I thought this error must have something to do with Proxy.

I moved to AWS EC2 instance. I cloned my gradle project on the ec2 instance, and did the same operation:

```
$ gradle uploadArchives
```

Success!

No change required in the code.

Simpler route of HTTP connection made me happy.